# load and combine all SAS dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have multiple SAS dataset in single location(folder) with two columns and name of the SAS dataset seems to be Diagnosis_<diagnosis_name>.

Here I want to load all dataset and combine all together like below,

Sample data set

```
File Location: C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\diagnosis\Diagnosis_<diagnosis_name>.sas7bdat

1. Dataset Name : Diagnosis_Diabetes.sas7bdat
```

[image]

```
2. Dataset Name : Diagnosis_Obesity.sas7bdat
```

[image]

```
Ouput which I expect like this
```

[image]

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have more than 200 sas dataset. I want to load all 200 dataset and and try to combine all ID and create flags against each ID. So that I could know how many users I have and what are the diagnosis they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine the datasets using SET statement. If want all of the datasets with names that start with a constant prefix you can use the `:` wildcard to make a name list.

First create a libref to reference the directory:

```
libname diag 'C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\diagnosis\';
```

Then combine the datasets.  If the original datasets are sorted by the PersonID then you can add a BY statement and the result will also be sorted.

```
data tall;
  set diag.diagnosis_: ;
  by person_id;
run;
```

If want to generate that wide dataset you could use PROC TRANSPOSE, but in that case you will need some extra variable to actually transpose.

```
data tall;
  set diag.diagnosis_: ;
  by person_id;
  present=1;
run;

proc transpose data=tall out=want(drop=_name_);
   by person_id;
   id diagnosis;
   var present;
run;
```